# how to init a tableViewCell with style excepted default?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I code a tableView using UITableViewCell.
I regist cell at viewDidLoad like this

```
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kMineCellidentifier)
```

and using at cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kMineCellidentifier, for: indexPath)
```

but this init with style default ,how do I init cell by style value1?

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-set an existing `UITableViewCell`'s style. But you can do this at the time of creating a `Cell` by convenient inits. Like:

```
UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "SomeIdentifier")
```